Does this Asst. Prof. email, to university COO, constitute non-academic misconduct?
I am dumbfound by this Assistant Prof.'s email to Chief Operating Officer

Is this tone professional? Perhaps I am too modest a violet.
Or is it grievable? Does it flout Columbia's rules, standards of behavior? https://www.college.columbia.edu/facultyadmin/dus/grievances

The Columbia faculty hold themselves to the highest professional standards, but from time to time there may be concern that their professional conduct is not consistent with the standards that the faculty have established for themselves. Those rights, duties, and obligations are delineated in the University Statutes and in the Faculty Handbook and can be found on-line at: http://www.columbia.edu/cu/vpaa/fhb/main.html.

But this link is broken.

This post appears to violate the policy on accusations against named individuals.

I’m voting to close this question because it violates the policy of naming individuals. See comment for meta post.

I don't understand why this question is being downvoted - it is a valid inquiry about what tone is acceptable in a challenging situation within an academic environment. I agree that the tone in this message seems quite aggressive at first, particularly when constrasted against the polite response that preceded the rather more emotional outburst.
This is perhaps a case where a bit of background information might help to explain the reaction. Looking into this myself out of curiosity, it seems that Prof. Davidai is not the first person to take umbrage with the pro-palestinean protests at Columbia University. Here is a recent New York Times article by another Columbia University professor who criticizes the form these protests take. Prof. Davidai also refers to the failure by the university leadership to speak out against Hamas, which might make more sense if contextualized against the congressional hearing last December, in which the presidents of Harvard, MIT, and the University of Pennsylvania failed to condemn calls for genocide.
Within that emotionally heated context, it may be more understandable why forms of civil debate may slip at times.

The question may be being downvoted by those who consider it not particularly relevant to the focus of this stack... ie it is not a problem but more of an opinion.

I agree with this answer. Also, I was reading this morning in Heather Cox Richardson's column that the President of Columbia told Congress that this particular professor had more than 50 complaints against him and was under investigation. So, that's at least some data in the "misconduct" column.

@DavidWhite "50 complaints against him and was under investigation" but not for his emails, or tone?

I see no problem with the tone of that letter: this is a person who apparently feels threatened at his place of work because of his ethnicity and/or religion. If that happens, you can respond a bit more direct than you would normally do.

I hesitate to endorce cursing out a colleague (or the Chief Operating Officer) on X. Probably not enough to lose tenure, but just not great politics or optics. These are extraordinary times, but readers should keep in mind that actions do have consequences and taking a firm and public stand against the administration might make your life harder afterwards as a professor.

@DavidWhite I see what you mean. However, if someone perceives something as antisemitic, then they are justified to voice their opposition robustly. As to the consequences of that robustness, they are going to be bad anyhow. I don't think cursing is going to make it any worse. Remember, such a person is accusing people of doing antisemitic acts or condoning those. There is no nice way to do that. So if someone decides to take that step, they have to be ready for a nasty nasty fight whatever tone they choose.
